# c# sql visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, c#-4.0

I accidentally deleted the main window `.aspx` in working `c#` in `webforms` application then it started showing this error how can I fix it.

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
 Error      
Unknown build error, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'    Test
```

Comment: If it deleted then Please check your Recycle Bin it may there copy and paste it.

Comment: you should have used any `version-control tool` like `git`

Comment: i copy and past it in its original folder and try running an it says can not locate resource mainwindows.xaml

Comment: @lazarus here is some confusion for me is in your question has webforms and .aspx pages and in your comment you add mainwindows.xaml which is WPF files. plz clear this for me

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the file to your solution? Adding it to the original folder might not be enough. Go to solution explorer and do the following:

- Click "Show all files"
- Right-click on the file you want to include.
- Click "Include in Project"

Once you've done this, try to build the solution and see if it gets rid of the error. If that doesn't work, I'd probably say your issue lies elsewhere.